# How to end a while loop when used in a fetch assoc function

Tags: php, errors

```
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()); ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['location']; ?></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

> syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE), expecting end of file *emphasized text*

Answer (score 1):

in `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc());` semicolon occored issue. replace `;` with `:`

```
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
       <tr>
          <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['location']; ?></td>
           <td></td>
        </tr>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
```